# Starting custom init.d script results in 404 page not found on localhost

Tags: bash, go, server, raspberry-pi3

I have an executable server file written in Golang which is ran by a custom script file, located in /etc/init.d/ directory on my Raspberry Pi 3B. The server starts but doesn't display the website I made in HTML. This website is located in a "static" folder in the same directory as my server executable.

I used this command to build the server.go into an executable.

```
go build server.go
```

**NOTE**

If I start the server manually by double-clicking it, the website works fine (my server displays the "static" folder).

My static folder consists of html, javascript and css files.

I think the problem is that when I start the server by a script, the static folder is not found by the server (displays: 404 page not found).

I would also like that the script is started whenever the RPi is booted.

I wrote the script following this site: https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question of system admin, so maybe better suited to https://serverfault.com/

That said, sounds like you want to set WorkingDirectory in your systemd unit so it can find your files (if using systemd).

```
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/server/dir
```

Adrian points out below that if you're using a bash script (as this is an old article) perhaps just add:

```
cd /path/to/server/dir
```

Comment: this means I move my static folder to the systemd unit, and the init.d server will find static folder?

Comment: Just noticed the instructions you're following are from 2012, I assume you're running a newer distro on your pi? If so just look up how to use a systemd unit instead, it'll be simpler and you can use the line above to set the working directory.  search for systemd rapsberry pi.

Comment: If there's already an init.d script, it's probably easier to add a simple `cd` command to that than to completely rebuild it as a systemd unit.

Comment: Yes if you're sticking with a bash script, just use cd.